# How to get buffer contents including line endings?

Tags: vimscript

I want to get the whole buffer contents as a single string.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
let line_ending = "\n"
let text = join(getline(1, '$'), line_ending).line_ending
```

But this assumes the line ending.  If this is the best approach, how can I find out what the line ending actually is?

Or is there a better way to get the actual buffer contents?

Comment: Why do you need it as a single string? NUL characters will be problematic.

Comment: To send it to another process.

Comment: You could send a list of lines, or the filename.

Comment: A list wouldn't contain the line endings.  The buffer might not be saved and therefore not have a file, or it might have changes which its file doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried `:%y` + `:echo @"` to see which line ending it uses?

Comment: @LucHermitte How would I see the line ending?

Comment: Good question. You could check each character individually, or split the string and check character with: `:echo map(split(@", '\zs'), 'char2nr(v:val)')`

Comment: The `fileformat` option looks like it gives me the buffer's line endings (assuming they are not mixed).

Comment: @LucHermitte I've just realised from [your comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12645/how-to-get-buffer-contents-including-line-endings/12651#comment21853_12645) that I could `%y` into a register and then assign the register's contents to a variable.  This seems the simplest approach.  If you could add this as an answer I'll be able to accept it :)

Comment: @AndyStewart. Done.

Comment: What exactly are you using that other process for? Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, [`:%!other-process`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#:range!) might do what you need. It filters the whole buffer (`%`) through `other-process`, and replaces the filtered lines with `other-process`'s output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to directly put the content of the current buffer into a register (and from here into a variable) thanks to `:%y` (`:yank` takes an optional register name).

However, after a test on a file in dos format, I've seen that my register contained characters of code 10 for newlines. The test being done with `:echo map(split(@", '\zs'), 'char2nr(v:val)')`.

I'm not sure why you want to extract the binary content of the buffer though -- IOW, I'm not sure to see why you want to keep the original line ending.

Answer (score 1):

The [`'fileformat'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileformat%27) setting control the end-of-line character that Vim uses. There are three possible values:

- `unix` – `\n`
- `dos` – `\r\n`
- `mac` – `\r` (this is very archaic and only applies to the pre-OSX "classic" MacOS
  of the 80s and 90s).

In VimScript this would be:

```
if &fileformat == 'unix'
    let line_ending = "\n"
elseif &fileformat == 'dos'
    let line_ending = "\r\n"
elseif &fileformat == 'mac'
    let line_ending = "\r"
else
    echoerr "unknown value for the 'fileformat' setting: " . &fileformat
endif
```

Or a shorter version:

```
let line_ending = {"unix": "\n", "dos": "\r\n", "mac": "\r"}[&fileformat]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I realised the [same thing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12645/how-to-get-buffer-contents-including-line-endings/12651#comment21857_12645) yesterday and wrote the exact same code you provided :)